# How to install tensorflow-probability in kaggle kernel for R language

Tags: r, kaggle, tensorflow-probability, greta

I need to install `tensorflow-probability` in kaggle kernel for R language.

I tried using the following code,

```
library(tensorflow)
install_tensorflow(extra_packages = "tensorflow-probability")
```

Which seems to only install tensorflow, as when I try to load package `greta`, which depends on tensorflow-probability, I get the following error,

```
Error: 

greta requires TensorFlow (>=1.10.0) and Tensorflow Probability (>=0.5.0), but TensorFlow Probability isn't installed. Use:

install_tensorflow(extra_packages = "tensorflow-probability") 
to install the latest version.
```

Also tried installing it through custom packages option, which shows it as installed, yet greta mentions it as being not installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key problem is that the preinstalled `r-tensorflow` virtual environment is not in a default location, which prevents the `install_tensorflow()` method from editing it. To resolve this, one first must set the `WORKON_HOME` environment variable that Reticulate uses to identify the root of the virtualenv environments.  I was able to get a proper installation along the following lines:

```
# set virtualenv root to where 'r-tensorflow' env is located
Sys.setenv(WORKON_HOME="/root/.virtualenvs")

# install greta
install.packages("greta")

# install tfp
tensorflow::install_tensorflow(envname="r-tensorflow", extra_packages=c("tensorflow-probability==0.3.0"))

# check that TFP is installed in the env
dir("/root/.virtualenvs/r-tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages")
## ...
## [56] "tensorflow"                            
## [57] "tensorflow_probability"                
## [58] "tensorflow_probability-0.3.0.dist-info"
## [59] "tensorflow-1.10.0.dist-info"
## ...
```

Along these lines, I made [a public Kaggle kernel available](https://www.kaggle.com/bioquant/greta-example?scriptVersionId=13051736) that runs the default Greta example.

The above code results in installing Greta v0.3.0, TF 1.10.0, and TFP 0.3.0, which is the correct version matching. I was also able to install the latest versions using

```
# set virtualenv root to where 'r-tensorflow' env is located
Sys.setenv(WORKON_HOME="/root/.virtualenvs")

# install latest greta
devtools::install_github("greta-dev/greta")

# install tfp
tensorflow::install_tensorflow(envname="r-tensorflow", version="1.13.1", extra_packages=c("tensorflow-probability==0.6.0"))
```

which also gets `library(greta)` to launch without complaint. However, it crashed during sampling, with a complaint about the `assertthat` package being corrupted. Note that `assertthat` gets updated as part of the Greta install from GitHub, which is why I ended up using the CRAN version.

Hopefully in the future Kaggle just includes TFP and one won't have to deal with this mess.

Comment: Thanks! I have also made a pull request to kaggle's R kernel to add tensorflow-probability and greta.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to say that the latest version of greta, about to be submitted on CRAN (so version > 0.4.0) uses a new approach with conda environments when using the new installation helper, `install_greta_deps()`.

This means greta will use conda environments to load python modules, so you can have different installations of python modules on your machine alongside greta.

When you run `library(greta)` it loads up the specific python module versions that greta needs. Hopefully this helps in the future!